# How to open URL in the same window in Node-Webkit?

Tags: javascript, node-webkit

```
var win = gui.Window.open('https://github.com', {
  position: 'center',
  width: 901,
  height: 127
});
```

This will open URL in a new window, but how do you open (redirect) the URL in the same main window?

Comment: I know I can do this:.  ```/nw path_to_app_dir --url="website-url"``` but need a way to redirect during application runtime... :( possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the normal HTML window functions.

```js
window.location.href = 'http://example.com';
```

Just be sure to include

```js
node-remote: 'http://example.com'
```

in your package.json if you plan to use the default nodewebkit functionality when that page is loaded.

Comment: tx for the answer, but I only know the web site at runtime, thus can't add it to package.json, so is the only option using iFrame :( ?